# What is wrong with this GNURadio flow graph?

Tags: gnuradio

I am simply trying to modulate a wav file sampled at 22.05kHz, then demodulate it.  The audio output is choppy and I get errors in the console output ("volk warning, no arch found... though I've run the profiler.  And aUaUaU....).  I guess the issue is with matching sample rates but I've gone through the graph several times and haven't found it.

Also maybe this is related: after I add the bottom row of components (channel model and beyond) the constellation diagram for the transmit side changes to flat.  Meaning, instead of a circle, it's a line (second screenshot below).  What's going on?

[image: flowgraph]

[image]

Comment: The sampling rate of the lower LPF seems to be off by a factor of 10.

Comment: please update to GNU Radio 3.8 or 3.9. We've greatly improved multiple blocks in your flow graph (fixed bugs in WBFM receive, for example). Anyways, are you sure you want to do a 10× interpolation on transmit? that sounds very much like overkill. then, 91× up, channel modell, then /91 down resampling makes literally no sense. Your channel has a length of 2, not 182... the plot you've done looks 100% correct, so I don't really know what you're asking us? These are real numbers, of course they are on the real axis?

Comment: @MarcusMüller sadly installing from source gave me multiple problems, I had to rely on my package manager.  Every few years I seem to try to install from source again for some new project, and every few years I run into another set of problems doing so.  And I'm using the directions provided for installing from source.

Comment: @MarcusMüller - Putting the response to your question in a separate comment: I am trying to reach the sample rate of the radio's I plan on using after it works in this form.  My target rate is 20M.  So it seems you see no errors in the plot (now that I've explained the interpolation)?  So the audio underflows and problems with the sound must be an issue with my system and/or gnuradio?

Comment: why would you need to install from source? On all modern Linux distros, GNU Radio 3.8 or 3.9 is what the package manager ships (so,update your linux every few years), and for older Ubuntu's there's a PPA.

Comment: nothing wrong far as I can see, only that the high resampling rates might lead to CPU congestion

Comment: @MarcusMüller I use mx linux and the what's available from my package manager is 3.7.  The debian / ubuntu repos provided from the gnuradio site weren't compatible (were for an old stable version or some other version compatibility issue).

Comment: @MarcusMüller do my interpolation rates make sense now that you know my target sample rate, or are they still strange?  Not sure if I've done that optimally

Comment: then update your linux. Using something that's outdated because you use an outdated linux is really not a great way to start a project.

Comment: @MarcusMüller my Linux isn't outdated.  You provide PPAs for Ubuntu and something for Fedora, the rest you suggest to use the distro's own package manager.  Following your recommendation (using my distro's package manager) I end up with 3.7.

Comment: which linux distro in which version are you using? I can *tell* yours is dated by the fact it's shipping GNU Radio 3.7 - which requires Python2, and thus has been kicked out by distro rules over the couple last years, as Python2 is EOL.

Comment: Note that the whole project would really love to enable people using their favorite version of GNU Radio for eternity, but with the volunteer hours we've got, that's not feasible, and once in a while, things like the Python2 abandonment we simply have to let old versions go less and less supported. This isn't to spite you, at all!

Comment: @MarcusMüller I use MX Linux, top of distrowatch now but a relatively recent Linux.  No, I get that open source software is hard.  I've run a few (very small) projects myself.  I am always understanding and thankful as long as the project maintainers are cordial.  We got off on a tangent, I gather that the version has nothing to do with my problem and you're just suggesting I update to enjoy newer features.  Strange I get all these aUaUaU... with or without a throttle, on powerful hardware.

Comment: @HH-ApologizetoCaroleBaskin nice, never heard of that one! It's based off a conservative Debian stable, so yeah, it's not exactly bleeding edge. You should, however, be pretty able to simply take the debian bullseye package and rebuild it. The fact that you get aU.. is, as said, probably due to the high resampling ratios, which really eat CPU, and the fact that WBFM was worse than it is now. Have you tried running `volk_profile` to help GNU Radio pick the best optimized code for your CPU? Will take a few minutes while it exercises all specialized SIMD kernels.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I can try to rebuild the bullseye package - thanks for the suggestion.  If that works I'll leave a note here to confirm.  High resample ratios... if I resample more times at lower ratios could it help?  I did run volk_profile and still get the no arch found warning regardless.

Comment: Yeah, there's a trade-off between resampling ratios and complexity, indeed. Try doing it in steps of 13 and then 7 while going up, and 13 and then 7 when going down. If you run `htop` and use its setup function to show you the names of userland processes, you have something where you can watch live which block consumes how much percentage of your CPU time.

Comment: @HH-ApologizetoCaroleBaskin I just tried starting a very plain build of GNU Radio 3.8.2.0-14 from bullseye on debian stable, didn't work out, as stable's debhelper seems to choke on an absence of Python3 plugin, and I'm not deep enough into debhelper to debug that quickly, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't alone it seems.  It is apparently a known issue and the solution here solved this for me as well: https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/issues/1516